# Flutter: making list item in list.generate

Tags: flutter, class, object, dart

i may not be able to explain properly..
i have created a list using `List.generate(9,(index) =>Container()`
in this list of 9 listitems I want to particularly give a random color  to 3 random items/containers of the list when i click on the container

```
GridView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                ),
                children: ListView(listLength, (index) {
                  final _isSelected = _clicked.contains(index);
                  return Center(

                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (_isSelected) {
                              _clicked.remove(index);
                            } else {
                              _clicked.add(in);
                            }
                          });
                      },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        curve: Curves.easeInQuad,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                              style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black),
                          color: _isSelected ? _color : Colors.white,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
```

Now in this i want to color each container with different color using Random() How can I do it?

Comment: did you mistake on typo `children: ListView` to `children: List.generate`?

Comment: no I have used 'List.generate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Widget**

```dart
class Applicants extends StatefulWidget {
  const Applicants({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Applicants> createState() => _ApplicantsState();
}

class _ApplicantsState extends State<Applicants> {
  Color _baseColor = Colors.blue;

  int listLength = 9;
  List<int> _luckyItems = [];

  //* import import 'dart:math';
  final Random random = Random();
  get randomColor =>
      Color((random.nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

  randomColorContainerIndex() {
    List<int> selected = [];

    while (selected.length < 3) {
      final i = random.nextInt(listLength);
      if (!selected.contains(i)) selected.add(i);
    }

    return selected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisSpacing: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 2,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
        ),
        children: [
          ...List.generate(listLength, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  print("item $index");
                  setState(() {
                    _luckyItems = randomColorContainerIndex();
                  });
                },
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  curve: Curves.easeInQuad,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black),
                    color:
                        _luckyItems.contains(index) ? randomColor : _baseColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.. I am begineer- intermediate level so this helped me a lot.  Still some modules need to be integrated then ill add this code and check it again..

Comment: glad to help you out.

Comment: can you suggest one more thing i.e, what can we use instead of index in this project. because index is being active only in the list scope . i want to use the data or item index outside list to make function.Let me know if any other way to use it.

Comment: let's separate the data from UI class, and use it here, some sort of state management property to handle everything and will be best practice.

Comment: now i want this random container which is changes onclick to go back to blue after 3 seconds. i am not able to do that.. in short you can check Block Memory game in playstore which I am trying to create as a beginner but i am not able to do properly

Answer (score 0):

If we are using list.generate dart method in between another list widget in flutter. We should use ...(Three dots) ie, Known as spread operator.

It is used to concatenate the generated list to another list in a widget. The answer provided above is correct.